# How to create a report on Custom Object Utilization per User in a Salesforce org

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I have a requirement to find out how many custom objects are utilized by each user in our Salesforce org. The reason to run this report is Salesforce has allocated a threshold value of Custom Objects that be allocated to each user in the org and we do not want to breach that limit. As of now I could find a way to find out Custom Object Utilization per User License. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_object_track.htm&type=0 
But my requirement is to link users and custom object, rather than user license and custom objects.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this through out of box or customization ?

Comment: Are you talking about data/record go to Storage Usage and see which user is using to data as well as which object has most record.

Answer (score 0):

You can view using Storage usage from Setup menu.

Storage usage displays:

- Data Storage
- File Storage

It has following sections:

- Current Data Storage Usage
- Current File Storage Usage
- Top Users by File Storage Usage

Click on user, you can view "User storage usage".

[image: user storage]